# How can I order these 2 foreach loops alphabetically

Tags: php, sorting, foreach

I have a foreach loop within a foreach loop
the first foreach loop grabs the department
the second foreach loop grabs the names within that department

```
<div class="selection">
<?php 
foreach ($departments as $department) {
  $code = $department['department_code'];
  $names = $department['department_names'];
  foreach ($names as $name) {
    $department_name = $name['name_of_department'];
    echo $department_name ;
  }
}
?>
</div>
```

currently the list sorts first by the department then the names which causes the alphabetical order to be broken, what can I add to make this code show the names in alphabetical order.

Comment: This code doesn't appear to do sorting of any kind. It's also unclear precisely what output you want. Are you saying you want all names in a simple list, regardless of the department? Some sample data and expected results would help here, really. I suspect you should probably merge all the arrays of names together, and then sort them (PHP has plenty of array-sorting functionality, and plenty of help is available online already for sorting multi-dimensional arrays etc, with simple googling), and then output them. But that's just a guess without being able to see any data (or read your mind).

Comment: See also [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue, if you need more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
    array_multisort(array_column($departments,'department_code'), SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING|SORT_FLAG_CASE,
                    array_column($departments,'department_names'), SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING|SORT_FLAG_CASE,
                    $departments);
```

That should put it in Code order then Name order where the Codes are the same

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the php `sort()` method to order the names in alphabetical order:

```
...
$names = $department['department_names'];

sort($names); // This will sort the $names in alphabetical order

foreach ($names as $name) {
    $department_name = $name['name_of_department'];
    echo $department_name ;
}
```

Full code with the sort:

```
foreach ($departments as $department) {
    $code = $department['department_code'];
    $names = $department['department_names'];

    sort($names); // This will sort the $names in alphabetical order

    foreach ($names as $name) {
        $department_name = $name['name_of_department'];
        echo $department_name ;
    }
}
```

One tip: try moving this logic away from your view. It looks like you are adding this logic in a `div` tag, what is located in a view file.

Such logic does not belong in a view.